# writing a binary file and getting its checksum

Tags: python, hash, binary, checksum

So I have written a binary file, and I am attempting to get the checksum of the File.  I am not sure whether I am understanding the hashlib library fully, or whether I am understanding exactly how to implement it.  Here is what I have, in Python 2.7:

```
def writefile(self, outputFile):
    outputFile = open(outputFile, 'wb+')
    for par in self.fileformat.pList:
        if par.name.lower() in self.calculated.final.keys():
            outputFile.write(self.calculated.final[par.name.lower()])
        else:
            outputFile.write(self.defaults.defaultValues[par.name.upper()])
    outputFile.close()

    with open(outputFile, 'rb') as fh:
        m = hashlib.md5()
        while True:
            data = fh.read(8192)
            if not data:
                break
            m.update(data)
        print m.digest()
    outputFile.close()
```

what I keep getting is :

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found
```

any help would be appreciated, because I could be headed in the completely wrong direction.

Comment: Can you give us the **full** traceback? Now we have to guess where the error occurs.

Comment: You don't need to do `outputFile.close()` at the end if you use `with`.  That's what it's for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake is in the second call to `open`:

```
with open(outputFile, 'rb') as fh:
```

Here, `outputFile` is the `file` object from the first `open` call, not the file name.  This cannot be used with `open`, which expects a string (or unicode) argument:

> TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found

The origin is the first line in the function body, where you overwrite the argument `outputFile`:

```
outputFile = open(outputFile, 'wb+')
```

To prevent these mistakes:

- Avoid re-assigning to argument variables
- Use better names: The argument `outputFile` is not expected to be a file, but a file name or path.  So name it `filePath` or similar.

Comment: This is correct, although a couple of points remain. It's very bad style to replace parameters in a method body, as it leads to these kinds of problems. Second, it would be more sensible to both write the file and compute it's digest in one pass.

Comment: Ah thank you I figured it out, that was silly of me.  I was too caught up in getting the hashlib to work I dont know what I was thinking